# How do I start to use multithread programming?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, unix, pthreads

I am a beginner on Stack Overflow.
I am working on a Unix platform in C/C++.
Knowing basic programming in these regards how could I start with [multithreading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multithreading)?

Multithreading seems to be very interesting and I want to grow my knowledge in this regard.

How could I get started with multithreading and what are the best techniques/books/ebooks/articles available to grab the concepts as early as possible?

Comment: Good answers below. I was afraid you'd get a ton of "use THIS API. It's zeh beeeeeeeeessst!!" but the most important point is what I will reiterate here: the API used is irrelevent. Most of the concepts apply regardless of API. Read some of the resources posted below. Pick a problem that you think you could parallize, then try it.

Comment: Whatever you do, start with a **high-level** API. Learn how to do stuff right before you learn how it works in detail.

Comment: @static_rtti to what point? understanding the basics of deadlock and mutual exclusion can't be avoided. Some lower-level API's facilitate this understanding more than the higher-level ones that do all of the locking for you once you enter a monitor's scope. I would recommend you start with the one that makes most sense to you, rather than worrying about if it's high or low level. Additionally, there would be those that argue against you, saying that until you know the details, then you DON'T know how to do it right. Your comment wasn't really helpful in any regard.

Answer (score 8):

Study regarding pthread, mutexes and try to implement same that will be beneficial for you.

http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html

Comment: yolinux is an awesome site with great information regarding what you need.

Comment: For stl containers also yolinux consist of very handy information for learning.

Answer (score 8):

Learning multi threading programming has two parts:

1. How to write multi threading applications
2. How to use the available API (pthread)

Learning multi-threaded programming is harder, thre's a good article published in the [Linux Journal](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/1363) that will help you understand the basic principles.

To better understand pThreads I suggest reading this tutorial - [POSIX Threads Programming](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/)

There is also a good book by O'rielly called [PThreads Programming](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565921153)

Comment: I agree with the O'Rielly book... I really clarified my understanding of multi-threaded programming by reading it, even though I ended up using a framework to help with some of the details in C++.

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting started with multithreading, my advice would be to first review and better understand I/O on your system.  Understand blocking vs. non-blocking I/O, signaling, asynchronous routines, callbacks et cetera.  I/O is probably one, if not the primary, reason for adding multithreading to your programs.  With that knowledge you can then pick up a book on pthreads or java threads, or wrap your mind around the Boost threads library or another threading library for your favorite technology.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the Wikipedia article [Multithreading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-threading) give you a quick overview and by following the external links you'll get a good overview of the topic.
After that - or additionally - you could read Tanenbaum's [Operating Systems: Design and Implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_S._Tanenbaum#Books) (great book by the way).
But the most important thing is - in my opinion - to get your hands on it. So just download a sample application from... let's say [The Code Project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Code_Project) or whatever website you'll find and play around with it. See how the application differs if you use locks or what happens if two threads try to access the same resource and how often this will occur, etc. 
By that I think you'll get the hang of it pretty quickly. And it's fun to evaluate and play around with techniques that are new to oneself.

Answer (score 1):

Something else to try: http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org

Answer (score 1):

I found this [tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) very informative and clearly-written. Hope it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit controversial, but multithreading really cklicked for me when I attempted to solve a coding puzzle once.

The puzzle was about writing thread safe code without using mutexes. My first attempts were miserable but when I finally got it, it was like learning to ride a bike - I've never felt unsure about concurrency ever since.

Some times I've even stumbled upon programmers who have read books on the subject, but fails to understand simple things like the fact that a primitive assignment may sometimes not be an atomic operation.

Comment: "a primitive assignment may sometimes not be an atomic operation. "

Many do not know that the assignment may not be executed in the order as written in the code and can infact be reordered by the compiler which can cause complications. I like the enlightening articles by Herb Sutter, Scott Meyers & Andrei Alexandrescu in this regard.

Comment: Was the puzzle's solution a lock-free design, or did it use a locking mechanism (such as Dekker's algorithm) other than a mutex (AKA dijkstra)? if it was a lock-free type of solution, would you mind posting the problem and solution somehow?

Comment: @San Jancinto: I actually don't remember such details about the puzzle. I also regret not saving it back then, this was about 8-9 years ago and the forum where it was posted doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to study the details try reading [Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment](http://www.kohala.com/start/apue.html).
or start with [Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective](http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/).

Answer (score 0):

Everything depends on you goals. There is plenty of code and articles with common multi-threading problems solved based on POSIX threads framework (I see number of recommendations of good articles here). The main question is what do you want to build. For some tasks it is not recommended to go multi-threading at all.

Here is book "[Foundations of Multithreaded, Parallel, and Distributed Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201357526)" which is related to discussed topic and which I'd like to recommend. The most significant advantage of it is 'relatively easy to read' style but no hard linkage to POSIX threads ideology (which is common problem).

Answer (score 0):

since it's UNIX why not start with processes and IPC comms? i.e. message queues, shared memory and mutexes.

Answer (score 0):

Studying various library frameworks and O/S facilities is a good way to understand low-level concurrency.  Examples you find there can get you started writing concurrent code in a short amount of time.

After you debug your way through a few deadlocks and shared memory corruption issues, you will find that you need some tools for reasoning about and decomposing your concurrency problems.  I personally like Herb Sutter's [The Pillars of Concurrency](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/200001985) article as a starting point.  The idea is to better understand why you need concurrency.  Are you looking for improved response time, parallel calculation, some combination of reasons?

Understanding the "why" will lead you to a better "what".  From there you can always spider out to different low-level approaches: [Active Objects](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/Act-Obj.pdf), [monitor objects](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/mpi.html), [message passing](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/monitor.pdf), [etc](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/patterns-ace.html#concurrent).  As you said, there is a lot to know in this field.